# Does the standard containers offer some caching features?

Tags: c++, caching, stl, containers, standard-library

If during the development of my application i will reach a point where i need to cache my data, does the STL library offers some kind of solution with its standard containers ?

Comment: "Caching" is awfully broad. It's far broader than, say, "LIFO queue".

Comment: @delnan "keep the data in memory for a faster access" sounds better ? on a file or in RAM?

Comment: Hardly. What kind of data? Where does it come from? How does one know when the cache is hit, and what should be returned for it? What caching strategy (LRU? LFU? somehing else?) And so on. Caching is a quite large field. Your question is slighty more specific than asking for "something that calculates numbers".

Comment: Just so you know, [the STL is not the standard library](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StlIsNotTheCppStandardLibrary).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: not that it makes any kind of real difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

(Dunno why StackOverflow wants 30 characters for an answer)